# GluonMobile change AppBar TextColor

Tags: textcolor, gluon-mobile, appbar

I tried to change the Text-color of a GluonMobile AppBar. It seems that the textcolor changes automatically depending on the background-color. Background-color is changeable via -fx-background-color or *-primary-swatch-500*. But *-fx-text-fill* in the same selector has no effect. My css looks like this.

```
.root {
    -primary-swatch-500: #a6d42e;   
}

.app-bar {
   -fx-text-fill:white;
   -fx-fill:white;
   -fx-font-color:white;    
}
```

I also tried to add the *important* keyword at the end,  but it still does not work. Additionally I tried to set i programmatically but found no way to achieve this. Has anyone had the same problem or any idea how to deal with that problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `.app-bar > .title-box > .label`. Also, use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) whenever you run into similar situations.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha thank you very much! That works. Unfortunately I cannot mark this as correct answer.